# How do I find all Azure AAD groups owned by one user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to find all the groups owned by an user. I can see all the groups the user is member of, but to find the owner I have to go one by one.
On the MS doc, it seems it's possible to filter by "User type" but I don't have that option in the search box. Maybe I miss a permission myself?
Or there is another way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in the portal GUI, but you could do this with PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all the Azure AD groups owned by a specific user, you can make use of below **PowerShell** cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADUserOwnedObject -ObjectId xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx | Select-Object ObjectID, ObjectType, DisplayName
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the groups owned by that user successfully like below:***

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can also make use of **[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**.

**Query:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_object_id/ownedObjects?$select=displayName,ID
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get-AzureADUserOwnedObject (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduserownedobject?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1-get-objects-owned-by-a-user)

[List ownedObjects - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)